# Apache Shiro, No GUI?

Tags: java, single-sign-on, shiro

We started to work on Apache Shiro as our authorization provider.
Many authorization providers have a user interface in order to define the users and their roles (Like a crowd, Open Am, etc..).

Do you know if Apache Shiro also supports some user interface or do we need to implement separate UI for defining roles and such?

Thanks,
ray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is a standard ui for editing users. We are using shiro with Vaadin and we have implemented user editing ourselves, using our own nosql db (neo4j).

We use spring for configuring shiro and created our own subclass of AuthorizingRealm to retrieve the users and add the correct permissions. This works create as this can also be used from a non-web environment.